# get Key production in Api manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

I'm working with WSO2 Api Manager version 1.6 and I need to obtain by a REST (or SOAP) service the Access Token (of Key Production) of the current suscription of an application.

Is it possible to obtain that key giving as input parameters user/pass of consumer (suscriber) user?

Answer (score 0):

There is token generation and renew method from client side,however you need consumer and secret key to generate this Token.

http://docs.wso2.org/display/AM160/Token+APIs

Answer (score 0):

Months ago I was working on that. I investigate trying with APIKeyMgtSubscriberService?wsdl. Try to call function getApplicationAccessToken by Soap UI. It returns keys you need, but I don't know why in my case returns some keys which are not equal to keys showed on the web interface. 
Hope it helps.